# Build error OpenCV on Eclipse in Windows

Tags: c++, eclipse, opencv, eclipse-cdt

i am new in OpenCV and i am trying to setup OpenCV in eclipse in Windows 7.

I have fallowed [this](http://opencv.itseez.com/doc/tutorials/introduction/linux_eclipse/linux_eclipse.html) tutorial and also i have set my path environment to openCv/bin directory but i still get an errors and cannot compile my project.

Here is my code and log ;

```
#include "opencv/cv.h"
#include "opencv/cxcore.h"
#include "opencv/ml.h"
#include "opencv/highgui.h"

using namespace std;

int main() {

    //new typename ImageIO::ImageIO;

    IplImage* img = cvLoadImage("Resources/imageDatabase/0000.jpg");
    cvNamedWindow( "1.Original Image", 1 ) ;
    cvShowImage( "1.Original Image", img );
```

ERRORS;

```
D:\Cagri\Job Information\Project\C++\ImageProcessingTool\Debug/../src/ImageProcessingTool.cpp:34: undefined reference to `cvLoadImage'
D:\Cagri\Job Information\Project\C++\ImageProcessingTool\Debug/../src/ImageProcessingTool.cpp:35: undefined reference to `cvNamedWindow'
D:\Cagri\Job Information\Project\C++\ImageProcessingTool\Debug/../src/ImageProcessingTool.cpp:36: undefined reference to `cvShowImage'
```

Please help me to solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a linker error, you should set the **-l** and **-L** options for the compiler. That's section 8.b in your tutorial.

Comment: I have set -l and -L options already but still getting this error message

Comment: i was using x64 bin directory and i change c86 its working now. But i do not understand why is not work in x64.